# Encountering 404 Not Found Error while setting up TFS 2015

Tags: tfs

I followed the instruction on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjjcqT5hZzI and was able to install TFS in my Windows Server 2012 successfully. I was able to access the TFS web site(http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/) from the browser so I thought it was all good.

When I tried connecting to it via Visual Studio 2015 Team Explorer, I got a 404 Not Found error. So I went back to my Windows Server 2012 and tested my Server URL in Team Foundation Server Administration Console. It gave me the same error. I can see it being hosted in the IIS properly and have been using Administrator account everywhere. The firewall is open for the port and I don't see how I can access the site but not the service on the same url.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the error I get while testing Server URL. Note that it is the same I get during attempts to connect via Team Explorer.

[image]

Comment: Can you open the web access ui locally on the machine where  you installed TFS?

Comment: Yes I can. http://localhost:8080/tfs/ works just fine.

Comment: Is your Visual Studio 2015 installed on the same Server 2012? Did it connect to any old TFS version (For example: TFS 2012) before? If yes, close VS and clean the TFS cache files. The cache folder locates at C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\cache. You may see several folders under Team Foundation folder like 4.0, 5.0, clean the cache file in all of them. And then try to connect to TFS server again.

Comment: This was a fresh TFS 2015 installation and we've never had Visual Studio installed on this machine..

Comment: @x0007me, is there any useful log file on the Logs page in TFS Administration Console?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT I just see one error log and it is the same one in that is in the image.

TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://localhost:8080/tfs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

It seems I had ISAPI Filter UrlScan setup at my connection level. It was being inherited into my site and was preventing my Team Explorer calls to fail. I took it off for now and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TFS IP address or server name to replace *localhost*, IP address is more recommended.

Comment: No luck when using IP address OR server name.

Comment: It seems your TFS is not configured well. Do you use a system account as the service account? Do you check the iis that TFS application pool is started? You may try to reconfigure the application tier by following the MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/TFS/setup/dual-server#Applicationtier

Comment: I used a service account which is and Admin for the machine as well. The same service account is sysadmin for SQL server

Answer (score 0):

1> Please go to IIS -> Sites -> Team Foundation Server -> tfs, click **Browse** to check whether whether the site can be opened correctly in browser. 
[image]

2> If the same issue happens, you can consider re-configuring TFS AT.

1. Navigate to the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools directory, and run the **tfsconfig setup /uninstall:all** command to unconfigure TFS.
2. Open the TFS Administration Console to reconfigure TFS.

Comment: The site opens correctly. I reconfigured the TFS as well  the problem still persists.